# Excel conditional calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a fixed cell value $50. A1

The next column contains a ratio - typically .2 to 2.0.  B1

What I want to calculate in an adjoining cell is a value based upon the ratios. C1

rules: if A1 is less than 1.0 multiply A1 by 20% and fill c1.
       if A1 is greater than 1.4 multiply by 50% and fill c1

```
   if A1 is greater than .9 or less than 1.41 C1 + A1
    ........if A1 is 1.0 to 1.4, multiply A1 by 100% and fill C1
```

help much appreciated so I can sleep..

Comment: What's the relevance of `B1`? It doesn't figure in the calculation.

Comment: A1 is fixed value. So did you actually mean B1 when you say if A1 is less than 1.0 multiply A1 by 20%? Are you actually checking B1 and then including A1 in calculation?

Comment: whoops; sorry about that - you are right; A1 is fixed, B1 is the variable AND c1 IS THE DERIVED VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

fill C1 with:

```
=A1*if(B1<1,.2,if(B1>1.4,.5,1))
```

This is the calcs it does:

B1 < 1, c1=a1*.2

B1 > 1, B1>1.4 then c1=A1*.5 else c1=A1*1